# Running Observable with Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, observable

I am trying to use Observable with regular Javascript. 
Followed instructions from here:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/rxjs

This is the sequence - not sure what is the problem:

```
    npm install rxjs
    npm WARN test@1.0.0 No description
    npm WARN test@1.0.0 No repository field.

    + rxjs@6.4.0
    removed 13 packages, updated 1 package and audited 2 packages in 3.163s
    found 0 vulnerabilities

    ------------------------------------------------------------
    » cat package.json                                                                                                                                                                
        {
          "name": "test",
          "version": "1.0.0",
          "description": "",
          "main": "counter.js",
          "dependencies": {
            "rxjs": "^6.4.0"
          },
          "devDependencies": {},
          "scripts": {
            "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
          },
          "keywords": [],
          "author": "",
          "license": "ISC"
        }

    ------------------------------------------------------------
    » cat obs.js  
      import { range } from 'rxjs';
      import { map, filter } from 'rxjs/operators';

      range(1, 200).pipe(
        filter(x => x % 2 === 1),
        map(x => x + x)
      ).subscribe(x => console.log(x));
    ------------------------------------------------------------
    » node obs.js                                                                                                                                                                     
        obs.js:1
        (function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { import { range } from 'rxjs';

        SyntaxError: Unexpected token {
            at new Script (vm.js:79:7)
            at createScript (vm.js:251:10)
            at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:303:10)
            at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:656:28)
            at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:699:10)
            at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:598:32)
            at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:537:12)
            at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:529:3)
enter code here            at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:741:12)
            at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:285:19)
------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: You seem to be trying to use ES module syntax (`import`).  You need to enable that whenever you start node using `--experimental-modules`.  See [ECMAScript Modules](https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html#esm_enabling)

Comment: Got error `node obs.js --experimental-modules
obs.js:1
(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { import { range } from 'rxjs';`

Comment: Notice the extension. It should be michael jackson script ',mjs'

Comment: @YuryTarabanko Strangely, I'm getting issues as well even with `.mjs`.  I can import everything with `import * as rxjs from "rxjs";` but destructuring isn't working.  I think it has something to do with needing a `.default`.

Comment: @YuryTarabanko Consider this: `import * as rxjs from 'rxjs'; const {range} = rxjs.default; console.log(typeof range);`  It's putting all the exports on the `default` of `rxjs`.

Comment: Yep it seems the problem with the fact that rxjs/index.js is compilted to commonjs format. `import rxjs from 'rxjs';
import operators from 'rxjs/operators';
const { range } = rxjs;
const { filter, map } = operators;` works

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something is frustratingly wrong with how the module imports are working with the RxJS package.  Whenever it is getting imported using `import * as rxjs from "rxjs"` all of the exported features are being attached to the `default` property of `rxjs`.  You then have to destructure them off of that property instead of `rxjs` itself.  For example, this should work if you use the following command:

Command (note the `.mjs` extension):

```
node --experimental-modules obs.mjs
```

Code:

```
import * as rxjs from 'rxjs';
const {range} = rxjs.default;
console.log(typeof range);
```

---

You could also just, not use modules and just use the `require` statements:

Command (note the **non** `.mjs` extension):

```
node obs.js
```

Code:

```
const { range } = require("rxjs");
const { map, filter } = require("rxjs/operators");

range(1, 200).pipe(
    filter(x => x % 2 === 1),
    map(x => x + x)
).subscribe(x => console.log(x));
```

---

Consider also, this issue on the GitHub [Provide named exports #3745](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/issues/3745)